# Using projects.operations.get method in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Here is the [link](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rest/v1/projects.operations/get) of the API doc I am trying

It **works in the try API panel.**

But **it's not working when I am doing a url_fetch** request using below code in python27:

```
encodedString = "projects/tuzzin-asf-qa/operations/ASAyNTAwNTEyNggadGx1YWZlZAcSMXMtc2Etc2Jvai1uaW1kYRAKJxI"      
url = 'https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/%s/operations/%s'  % (app_id, encodedString)
result = urlfetch.fetch(
 url=url,
 # payload=json.dumps(request),
 method=urlfetch.GET,
 deadline=60,
 headers=headers)
```

Even tried with encoded string:

```
encodedString = "projects%2Ftuzzin-asf-qa%2Foperations%2FASAyNTAwNTEyNggadGx1YWZlZAcSMXMtc2Etc2Jvai1uaW1kYRAKJxI "  
url = 'https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/%s/operations/%s'  % (app_id, encodedString)
result = urlfetch.fetch(
 url=url,
 # payload=json.dumps(request),
 method=urlfetch.GET,
 deadline=60,
 headers=headers)
```

Incase of encoded string it returns:

```
"error": {
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Operation does not exist",
  "status": "NOT_FOUND"
}
```

Comment: Your repeating the Project ID section in your url.

Comment: You are right , thanks.